# Chrome extension message queue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developing chrome extension, and after some additional scripts are almost done, I faced with messaging problem. I wrote some kind of test code, and noticed, that at a time, onMessage listener can process message only from one script. Here's testing code:

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request.action);
    if (request.action == 'first') {
         sendResponse({ action: 'first_next', arg: 1 });
    } else
    if (request.action == 'second') {
        sendResponse({ action: 'second_next', arg: 1 });
    }

    return true;
});

chrome.tabs.executeScript(active_tab, {file: 'first.js'});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(active_tab, {file: 'second.js'});
```

This background script listens and sends response for each message.

**first.js**

```
function wait() {
    done('OK');
}

function done(result) {
    var msg = { action: 'first', result: result };
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, function(response) {
        if (response.action === 'first_next') {
            setTimeout(wait, 400);
        } else 
        {
            setTimeout(wait, 2000);
        }
    });
}

wait();
```

**second.js**

```
function wait() {
    done('OK');
}

function done(result) {
    var msg = { action: 'second', result: result };
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, function(response) {
        if (response.action === 'second_next') {
            setTimeout(wait, 400);
        } else 
        {
            setTimeout(wait, 2000);
        }
    });
}

wait();
```

So, console log should be like:

```
first
second
first
...
first
first
second
first
second
...
```

But, it is:

```
first
second
second
second
second
second
...
```

That says that I can process only one message in time. And i don't know how to solve my problem, maybe something like messaging queue (idk how to do this) or smth else ? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here isn't with the Chrome API. You have two functions with the same name injected onto the page. So basically the following happens:

1. You inject `first.js` and it executes `done` function
2. You inject `second.js` and it executes `done` function
3. `done` from `second.js` overwrites the defintion of `done` from `first.js`
4. Each time `first.js` calls `done` it will call the `done` as defined in `second.js`

To see a proof of this, change `done` in `second.js` to `done2` and then execute the code. You should get the desired results.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right! Is it a way to separate namespaces ?